# Easiest way to build a Karaf plugin

Tags: java, maven, apache-karaf

I have prior Java coding experience but not so much knowledge of the whole diverse Java Ecosystem. I have now been tasked to develop a small Karaf plugin for a huge system. This system is utilizing countless of Java goodies: Camel, Karaf, Maven and whatnot. I have some example code that I would need to do some minor changes in and rebuild.

The example is a Maven project (atleast there are a pom.xml) and it should be a Karaf plugin in the end. What is the easiest way to do the changes to the example and rebuild the plugin? I have never used any of the above before and the changes are small so installing and configuring alot of stuff seems a bit overkill.

Where to start? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with tech-idiot, your best bet is spending some time with the *karaf-maven-plugin*, but you can also set the bundle up by hand, at least to realize that it could be easily achieved with the help of the maven plugin (specially if you have a lot of dependencies).

A basic OSGI bundle (what you refer as "plugin"), is nothing else than a *JAR* file with a special plain text file in there, the *MANIFEST.MF* file.

The *MANIFEST.MF* describes the bundle, its name, description, how you want to activate it, and what the bundle *requires* to run (its dependencies, or *imports*), as well as what it has to offer to the other bundles (its *exports*).

That's a sample manifest file taken from the [wikipedia OSGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi#Bundles) entry:

```
Bundle-Name: Hello World
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.wikipedia.helloworld
Bundle-Description: A Hello World bundle
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-Activator: org.wikipedia.Activator
Export-Package: org.wikipedia.helloworld;version="1.0.0"
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0"
```

The *MANIFEST.MF* file is usually packed in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` folder of your jar, so:

- You can write that file by hand and add it manually to your generated jar.
- Probably, from the last three elements of the sample manifest, you'll only need the `Import-Package` section (no `Bundle-Activator` and no `Export-Package`)
- You should declare in the `Import-Package` **each required external** package import for your app and its **version**. Keep in mind that the external dependencies you use in your app must be available in the OSGI runtime for your bundle to run.

Comment: Thank you for an excellent answer! I had come to the conclusion that it was basic JAR. I will look into Maven sometime in the future but for now this is enough (small change).

Answer (score 3):

Maven already provides a plugin for karaf , only thing that you have to do is to attach it .

For more reference you can see the below link.

http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/developers-guide/karaf-maven-plugin.html

Thanks

Comment: As I mentioned I have never used Maven or Karaf, done mostly .NET and web. That page says like nothing to me, quite steep learning curve.

Hence the where to start in the first post. This is most likely a one time change and a minor one so a quick and dirty solution would be more than fine.

Comment: As a suggestion first get some basics of maven from here - http://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html and then i think above URL will make much more sense. - Thanks

Comment: Start learning plain Java first, then go for maven and after you got your basics settled go for OSGi and learn how to build modular applications.

Comment: Plain Java I have some knowledge about. But this is a small plugin and hence I wanted to get it done as quickly as possible. 

I know it's not the right way of doing it but is it possible to deploy any jar into Karaf? Eclipse project -> Export as jar -> copy to Karaf deploy folder. What are the absolute minimum to get it working?